# How do I write a bash script that logins into Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: 14.04, bash, virtualization, scripts

How do I write a bash script that

first: login in to Ubuntu virtual machine

second: open terminal in VM and pass command in it?

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Use `ssh` just like connecting to any other computer.

Comment: Set up port forwarding in virtual machine options, then ssh to it as glenn suggests

Comment: Openssh server will need to be installed on VM by the way

Comment: Is there any way I can do it using script/programming?

Comment: Yes, SSH will give you a terminal just like any other one.  Whatever you can do from a Terminal you can do over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have open a terminal window and you can login on you VM via [ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH).

Create a file ~/hello.sh with the next content:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/testdir
cd ~/testdir
echo "Hello" > hello.txt
```

Next run the follow command

```
ssh user@host < hello.sh
```

You will be asked for password and the script will be run.

If you use certificate (recommended) change the command with

> ssh -i path_to_sert user@host < hello.sh

Log via ssh and check what you have

> cat ~/testdir/hello.txt

Answer (score 0):

By your question it seems that you want to log in to Ubuntu via GUI, then open a window with a terminal in it and execute some commands there. I may have misunderstood your question though. Please let me know if that's the case.

That's not a practical way to do it, and normally we'd rather use ssh to connect directly to the VM using the terminal on your physical computer. This means you can execute commands on your VM, but the output will be sent to the terminal on your physical computer - they won't show up on the VM's GUI screen with a terminal window open.

For this to work you must know your VM's IP address and install sshd (sudo apt-get install openssh-server) on the VM, then in your physical computer's terminal, you can execute:

```
ssh [VM's ip address]
```

to simply log in to its shell, or

```
ssh [VM's ip address] command
```

to execute [command] on the VM. If [command] is a shell script, it needs to be a shell script on the VM. You can also execute commands directly, for example:

```
ssh 192.168.0.100 ls -la
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its really helpful. Just wondering, when I type ssh 192.168.0.100 ls -la in the terminal, it lists all the files and exits the ssh.Is this normal? What if I don't want to exit the ssh connection. Secondly, If I want to go to a directory and execute a command..? How to do this with single ssh command?(FYI: I tried doing this:   ssh 192.168.0.100 cd /Desktop/folder ls -a ...But it only build an ssh connection and doesn't execute the remaining cd /Desktop ... command.)

Comment: Yes, when you execute `ssh 192.168.0.100 ls -la` it is supposed to exit afterwards. To go to a directory, then execute a command you can use semicolon to separate commands, or && if you want to execute the next command only if the previous one was successful. It's important that you enclose the commands in double quotes though, otherwise the second command will be executed locally. For example: `ssh 192.168.0.100 "cd some-dir; ls -la"`

Comment: Better yet, in order to stop executing commands should any of the commands return an error, use && instead of ; like this: `ssh 192.168.0.100 "cd some-useless-dir && rm -rf ."` . Obviously, you need to be careful with `rm -rf .`, but it's just a worst case scenario example. That command would wipe your home directory should `some-useless-dir` not exist had you used semicolon instead of &&. && is like saying "and if that went well, ...". The opposite is ||, which can be read "or if that didn't work, try ...".

Comment: I don't know of a way to execute a remote command, then stay in the remote console. As far as I know, you have to choose either to interactive or not.

Comment: @Dana does this answer your question?

Comment: That's good to hear, and no problem.  If you feel it helped you, I would be grateful if you could upvote and choose my answer as the best answer as I  think I get reputation point for that (which of course would make me insanely happy). It also marks the question as answered, as far as I understand.